# Error with Basic Method While Using Cengage

Tags: c#, methods, error-handling, compiler-errors

I am a student and I am taking a class in C#. Right now we are learning the basics of Methods and the class utilizes Cengage for the learning environment. My code runs fine, but it does not seem to be good enough for Cengage. I have had a couple problems with the sandbox opening with a couple other assignments, but It just feels like I'm missing some pedantic criteria to receive full credit.

I have taken a day to leave and then return back and I am still having trouble understanding the problem that has arisen. any help or at least a hint would be much appreciated.

**ASSIGNMENT INSTRUCTIONS**:

Previously, you wrote a program named Admission for a college admissions office in which the user enters a numeric high school grade point average and an admission test score. The program displays Accept or Reject based on those values. Now, create a modified program named AdmissionModularized in which the grade point average and test score are passed to a method that returns a string containing Accept or Reject.

**WHAT IS BEING TESTED:**

Cengage is testing for:

- Desired Output by having the program entering numbers and seeing if it prints correctly and if the logic is correct [I receive full credit for this]
- If the method executes correctly [I get no points here]

I will put the Error messages/exact wording for testing I have received below

**CODE**:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
class Admission
{
   static void Main()
   {
     
            double gpa = 0;
            int testScore = 0;
            

            AcceptOrReject(gpa, testScore);
   }



    public static string AcceptOrReject(double gpa, int testScore)
   {
     string accept = "Accept";
     string reject = "Reject";
     string inputString;

     
     
     WriteLine("Enter grade point average ");
     inputString = ReadLine();
     gpa = Convert.ToDouble(inputString);

     WriteLine("Enter test score ");
     inputString = ReadLine();
     testScore = Convert.ToInt32(inputString);

            if (gpa >= 3.0)
                if (testScore >= 60)
                {
                    WriteLine(accept);
                    return accept;
                }
                else
                {
                    WriteLine(reject);
                    return reject;
                }

            else
                if (testScore >= 80)
                {
                    WriteLine(accept);
                    return accept;
                }
                else
                {
                    WriteLine(reject);
                    return reject;
                }
   }
}
```

**PURPOSE OF PROGRAM:**

The program takes in two user inputs, one for a GPA and one for a test score. The program then compares the two user inputs based on criteria listed in the code and when the method is called it prints "Accept" or "Reject" based on those inputs and if/else logic.

**ERROR CODES**:
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings

1. The `AcceptOrReject` method did not return the expected string.
2. NtTest94010e11.cs(5,14): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `AdmissionModularized' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

**LOGIC FOR TEST BEING USED:**

```
[TestFixture]
public class NtTest94010e11
{
    [Test]
    public void Test482()
    {
                Assert.IsTrue(AcceptOrReject(3.5, 95) == "Accept");
    }
}
```

Please, Please , Please help me. I would really like to understand this to help me better avoid any mistakes I could have made, but I really have tried to finish this by myself,

The program works fine in terms of what it is supposed to. It runs and you get the desired results.

1. I have tried changing what is returned to see if it was something just not printing exactly what the question asks
2. I have tried changing the names of the class, methods, and variables used in the program.
3. I have tried creating another file from which I could call the method in order to call it using a class name.
4. I have tried calling the method with a class name.
5. I have tried adding a namespace from the original program file and in a new program file.

   I just keep getting half of the assignment's credit.

Answer (score 0):

I took the same class, it is an error in the code already in place.

Add Modularized at the top next to Admission:

class AdmissionModularized